# Problems in State Updates using React Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am facing an issue with state updates while using Context API in React. I have created a UserId context to obtain the userId and make subsequent requests to my backend. Would you please have a look at the code? This is the UserIdContext.jsx -

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const UserIdContext = createContext();
export const UserIdProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
  return (
    <UserIdContext.Provider value={{ userId, setUserId }}>
      {children}
    </UserIdContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const useUserId = () => {
  return useContext(UserIdContext);
};

UserIdProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired, 
};
```

This is where the state changes are supposed to happen, I have imported UserIdContext on top.

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  const { userId, setUserId } = useUserId();
  const addUser = async () => {
    if (user && isAuthenticated) {
      try {
        const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
        const response = await axios.post(
          API_BASE + '/users',
          {
            headers: {
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          }
        );
        const user_id =  response.data.data.user._id;
        setUserId(user_id);

        console.log(userId);
        console.log(user_id);
        
        } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    addUser();
  }, []);
} `
`

export default Sidebar;
```

I have called setUserId(user_id), however when I console.log(userId), it returns null, It could be due to the asynchronous nature of js but also the subsequent request to getEntries fails inside the  component.
However, when I make a minor change in code, and Vite restarts the app, the state updates are made, and console.log(userId) actually returns the user_id.